# Swift Parse Saving an Annotation from MapView as a PFGeoPoint

Tags: swift, parse-platform, annotations

I have an app where I have the user chose a location on MapView where their brand is based. When they tap a location on the map it creates an annotation with a title as well as subtitle. What I'm trying to do now is convert this annotation to a PFGeoPoint when the user hits "next" button so that it can be saved to Parse and later queried and displayed on a map for every user to see.

Here is the code that allows the user to create an annotation for their location:

```
//Annotations
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){

    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)

    let coordinate = map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()


   if isAnnotated == true {

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = PFUser.current()?.username

    annotation.subtitle = (PFUser.current()?.username)! + " is based here!"

    //removes annotation
    let allAnnotations = self.map.annotations
    self.map.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)

    //adds annotation
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print("REMOVED")

    isAnnotated = false

    } else {

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = PFUser.current()?.username

    annotation.subtitle = (PFUser.current()?.username)! + " is based here!"

    //removes annotation
    let allAnnotations = self.map.annotations
    self.map.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)

    //adds annotation
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print("ANNOTATION ADDED")

    isAnnotated = true

    }
}
```

What I need now is to save the annotation as a PFGeoPoint, however I'm not too sure how to go about it. It seems that PFGeoPoint wants the location in the form of CLLocation, but I don't know how to convert the annotation to that. I can provide the code I have so far for saving it to Parse if need be, but it's really scrambled as I don't know how to get the annotation into a format that can be saved to Parse. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT - Here is my code, I now just need a way to save the geoPoint variable that includes the annotation coordinates as a PFGeoPoint under the "next" func

```
    import UIKit
    import Parse
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class BrandLocation: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

var isAnnotated = false

@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

//QUESTIONABLE
var currentLoc: PFGeoPoint! = PFGeoPoint()

//QUESTIONABLE
var MapViewLocationManager:CLLocationManager! = CLLocationManager()

//ANNOTATION DECLARED
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

//Defines geoPoint as nil
var geoPoint : CLLocationCoordinate2D! = nil


func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}


//THIS IS WHERE PFGEOPOINT IS SAVED
@IBAction func next(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    let brandLocation = PFObject(className: "location")


    //this is the main problem, I'm not sure how to take the coordinates I've defined in the geoPoint variable and now save them as a PFGeoPoint
    geoPoint = PFGeoPoint(location: )

    geoPoint["brandLocation"] = self.map.annotations

   // let geopoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    brandLocation["annotationTitle"] = self.map.annotations

    brandLocation["annotationSubtitle"] = self.map.annotations

    brandLocation.saveInBackground { (succes, error) -> Void in

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if error != nil {

            self.createAlert(title: "Could not update profile", message: "There was a problem updating your profile")

            print(":(((")

        } else {

            self.createAlert(title: "Profile Updated", message: "Profile details successfully updated")

            print("MAPPED")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUserFeed", sender: self)

        }

    }

    // self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUserFeed", sender: self)

}


//VIEW DID LOAD
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black

    locationManager.delegate = self

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    let uipgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(BrandLocation.longpress(gestureRecognizer:)))

    //uipgr.minimumPressDuration = 1

    //uipgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    map.addGestureRecognizer(uipgr)

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {



}


//Setting up map & location zoom
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


}

//Annotations
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){

    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)

    let coordinate = map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)


    //DECLARED ABOVE
    //let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    //WORKING ON GEOPOINT
    // currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: MapViewLocationManager.location)

    //Declares and defines geoPoint

    let latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude

    let longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude

    self.geoPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)


   if isAnnotated == true {

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = PFUser.current()?.username

    annotation.subtitle = (PFUser.current()?.username)! + " is based here!"

    //removes annotation
    let allAnnotations = self.map.annotations
    self.map.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)

    //adds annotation
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print("REMOVED")

    isAnnotated = false

    } else {

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = PFUser.current()?.username

    annotation.subtitle = (PFUser.current()?.username)! + " is based here!"

    //removes annotation
    let allAnnotations = self.map.annotations
    self.map.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)

    //adds annotation
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print("ANNOTATION ADDED")

    isAnnotated = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use annotation coordinate to set a geopoint.

```
let latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude
let longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude
let geopoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```

for you save function

```
for annotation in self.map.annotations {
    //get location of all annotation
    let latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude
    let geoPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    //save in Parse object
    let brandLocation = PFObject(className: "location")
    brandLocation["annotationTitle"] = annotation.annotationTitle
    brandLocation["annotationSubtitle"] = annotation.annotationSubtitle
    brandLocation["geoPoint"] = geoPoint
    brandLocation.saveInBackground { (succes, error) -> Void in 

    ....

    }
}
```

Comment: but how do I take the annotation coordinate that was chosen by the user and convert it to a latitude and longitude that can be saved as a PFGeoPoint to parse?

Comment: Okay thanks that seems like it'll work. However, the problem I'm having is that I need to save the PFGeoPoint in a separate function called "next" that is different than the function that creates the annotation. How can I call on geopoint outside of the annotation function so that I can save it  as a PFGeoPoint when the user clicks next?

Comment: That's a different question. You could save the geopoint in a (the view controller) class variable. Just define var geoPoint : CLLocationCoordinate2D! = nil and save and recall it there from via self.geoPoint. Just send me a PM with your code if you need more help.

Comment: Check out the code I added above under EDIT. I really appreciate the continued responses Lengo!!!!!!

Comment: check out the "next" function and if you can give me a suggestion on how I can save PFGeoPoint

Comment: Great, for other users visiting this thread, could you select this answer as the correct one?

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks again for your help, if you could check out a separate question I just asked and try to help me that'd be so awesome! It's a small problem that has to do with the query I'm running to display these annotations on a mapview. Thanks!